# How to change the value of a column based on a substring of it?

Tags: mysql, sql, substring, vertica

I am pulling data from a database for analysis and have encountered a problem. Essentially I have a column that denotes the progress plan of a sale. The values of these columns can be "Green", "Red" or "?", but they each have a unique description following them such as `Green - Good to proceed`, `Green- Ready to move forward` or `Red -Do not proceed` etc.

The only data I need is the respective "Red" "Green" or "?" value, I don't need the description following them. At the moment all I am doing is taking the first letter of each row using SUBSTRING, so I end up with values such as `R, G, R, ?, ? etc..` Then in excel I can do a find and replace to rename them, but this is an extra step that I don't think is necessary. If I try and take the first 5 letters, I will end up with data such as `Red -, or Red-D` for certain rows, which I cannot work with.

Is there a way I can change the value of the column in my query? I have tried something along the lines of

```
SELECT CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(columnName, 1, 1) = 'G' THEN 'Green'
       ,CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(columnName, 1, 1) = 'R' THEN 'Red'
       etc.....
```

where I try to change the value based on the substring value, 
but this does not work. Can anyone offer an alternative solution to this?

Comment: Create a table like `progress_type(progress_type_id, color, shortcut description)` and only store a foreign key `progress_type_id` in your data table.

Comment: Judging from the variance shown on the notes following the colors, the "description" would probably need to remain in the original table; but I agree about moving the progress "code".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this . Here is the [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4a093/5)

```
 select case substring(mystring,1,1)
        when 'G' then 'Green'
        when 'R' then 'Red'
        else '?'
    end as mycolumn from test;
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems to have worked like a charm! Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `substring` and `instr`.

```
select substring(columnname,1,instr(columnname,'-')-1) as color
from tablename
```

Answer (score 0):

If the values always contain characaters `' -'`, and we want to return just the characters that appear *before* that, we could use MySQL `SUBSTRING_INDEX` function.  For example:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.mystring,' -',1) 
     , ...
  FROM test t
```

Note that if there are any values of mystring which do not contain the characters `' -'`, then the expression will return mystring in it's entirety.

This just one of many possible expressions.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Unfortunately not all the data is formatted like that. @cableload's suggestion seems to have worked for me though, so I think I'll go with that for the moment

Answer (score 0):

Like can be used when a bit more flexibility is needed, and will ensure you can worry less about someone inserting 'Grey'.

```
SELECT CASE
      WHEN columnName LIKE 'Green%' THEN 'Green'
      WHEN columnName LIKE 'Red%' THEN 'Red'
      ELSE '?'
      END AS `status`
FROM ....
```

Also, `LIKE` statements that do not start with wildcards *can* sometimes take advantage of indexes; function calls like `SUBSTRING` almost never (if ever) can.